# Find, Replace and Formula

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, vba

I want to look for all instances of a word in a particular column (eg. Apple) and replace the contents (eg. Banana) and then on the same row in a different column that already holds a value (eg. 50) insert a formula to calculate 95% of that value (eg. =50*95%).

I have recorded the macro and have achieved this:

```
Sub Apple50toBanana95()

    ' Find Apple
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AV$1600").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "Apple"
    Range("A2").Select
    ' Replace Apple with Banana
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Banana"
    Range("A2").Select
    'Calculate 95% of the value
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=50*95%"
    Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

It will only run for the first record in row two. Is there a way to apply it to all instances?

Comment: (Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Banana" and then Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=50*95%") doesn't make any sense.  did you mean replace the column A from apple to banana then same row on column b insert calculation?

Comment: @krishKM Yes, that is correct. Sorry, VBA and Macros are rather new to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") ' Set your search range
    Set c = .Find("Apple", lookin:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = "Banana" ' Replace value
            'add further operations using excel offset feature like c.Offset(1, 1).value = something

            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```